# How to keep text in textarea remain at the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an application here: [HERE](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/InputTest.php)

In application please do the following:

1. In the text area at top type in some content
2. Click on `Add Question` button to append content into table below. You can see the content in the textarea in the table is placed at the top of the textarea.
3. Now you will see a file input, please upload an image using the file input.
4. Now when the upload finishes, it appends the name of the file, a hidden input and a remove button underneath, but look at the textarea with your content in ther other column, the text has moved down a space. It has not stayed on top.

That is my question, how in this situation am I able to keep the text in the text input remain at the top of the textarea?

Below is the main code:

The textarea and file input appended into the table row:

```
var count = 0;
var gQuestionIndex = 0;

function insertQuestion(form) {   

      var questionarea=(form.questionText.length)
                ? form.questionText[0]
                : form.questionText;


    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $question = $("<td width='13%' class='question'></td>");
    var $image = $("<td width='17%' class='image'></td>");
    var $questionType = '';

    gQuestionIndex++;


    $('.questionTextArea').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

    $question.append($questionText);

    });



    var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
    "<p class='imagemsg'></p></label>" +
    "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "<p class='listImage'></p>" +
    "<iframe class='upload_target_image' name='upload_target_image' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");     

    $image.append($fileImage);


    $tr.append($question);
    $tr.append($image);
    $tbody.append($tr); 

    count++;

    $(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum);

    form.questionText.value = "";

    $('.questionTextArea').val('');


    setWidth();

}
```

The `setWidth()` code where it ensures the textarea remains filling the table cell if the table cell has it's height and width changed:

```
function setWidth() {
    $(".textAreaQuestion").each(function(){
     var questionCellWidth = $(this).closest(".question").width();
    var questionCellHeight = $(this).closest(".question").height();
    $(this).css({
        "width": (questionCellWidth - 6) + "px",
        "height": (questionCellHeight) + "px"
    });

    });
  }
```

The stop uploading function where it appends the filename, remove button and hidden input:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imageID, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';   
            $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<input type="hidden" name="imgid[]" id="'+imageID+'" value="' + imageID + '" />');
            $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" data-imageID="'+imageID+'"  data-image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');
         }


      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').html(result);
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').css('visibility','visible'); 
      $(sourceImageForm).find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');


      return true;   
}
```

Finally below is the css for the textarea:

```
.textAreaQuestion{
    width:100%;
    resize:none;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    display: block; 
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding to your CSS:

```
td.question {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

The problem is that your right-hand column is creating more vertical space, and your cells are set to their normal state, which starts text vertically-aligned in the center of the cell.

Better, even, would be something like this:

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 1em .5em; /* or something to this effect, 
                          to normalize the spacing of 
                          data from the cell-sides */
}
```

This way, no matter how much information is added to the right-most column cell, all the cells will start aligned to their tops at about the same place. You might have to also adjust some margin spacing around the textarea, if you want to really align the text, but this should at least get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the text is in the top of the textarea with any inspecting tool (Chrome or Firefox recommended anyway). Screenshot attached:

[image]

The problem, as mori57 says, is that the new text is creating more space. His solution should work, but why don't you create the text where there's now an empty spot? Where there is the "loading" image that disappears after loading, put the text of "image uploaded" there. You can see what I mean more clear in the 3D screenshot I attached, the orange bit.

OR, if you don't do this, you can at least hide that html bit (change the style to `display: none;`).